# Assign HTML button id dynamically using Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-promise, angular2-observables

I'm having trouble assigning the ID attribute to some HTML buttons.

**categories.service.ts:**

```
getCategories(): Observable<Category[]> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': this.authenticationService.token });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.get(this.categoriesURL, options)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }
```

**categories.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Category } from '../../_models/category';
import { CategoriesService } from '../../_services/categories.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-categories',
  templateUrl: './categories.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./categories.component.css']
})
export class CategoriesList implements OnInit {
  categories: Category[] = [];

  constructor(private categoriesService: CategoriesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Limpia el mode
    this.categoriesService.clearMode();
    // Lista de categorías
    this.categoriesService.getCategories()
        .subscribe(categories => {
          this.categories = categories;
        });
  }

  setMode(event){
    this.categoriesService.setMode(event.target["name"], event.target["id"]);
  }

}
```

**categories.component.html:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Nombre</th>
                  <th>Descripción</th>
                  <th></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let category of categories">
                  <td>{{category.name}}</td>
                  <td>{{category.description}}</td>
                  <td><button (click)="setMode($event)" routerLink="/categories/form" type="button" name="editando" id="{{category.id}}" class="btn btn-info"><i class="ti-pencil-alt"></i> Editar</button></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Explanation:** When "/categories" loads, triggers the getCategories() function that retrieves data from the server. Then it populates my table in the view and builds each row with an edit button with the category id as the button id at the end. What I'm doing is when the user clicks the edit button, triggers the setMode() function in categories.component.ts and retrieves the button ID and saves the mode and ID in the service. This mode will be used when viewing the edit form (because I use it for creating and editing the same resource) The ID will be used for requesting the resource to the server.

**Error:** Sometimes, when I click the edit button, it navigates to the form but doesn't make the call to the server to retrieve the resource (I checked the network tab in Chrome). I console.logged the ID in the setMode() function and noticed that sometimes it is undefined so I don't think my problem is in the form. It happens randomly, sometimes I click the edit button 5 times and it works and the next gives me undefined and sometimes more or less. So I think it could be something with my requests but I'm not sure.

What I already tried:

- Changing Observable to Promise
- Not rendering the list until the data
  is retrieved from the server (using Observable and Promise)

Comment: Not really related but is there a reason for you not to do `setMode(category.id)`? Also, if navigation seems too happen to early, why not navigate via code at the end of your setMode method?

Comment: @Ploppy in setMode i'm passing the event object, there I'm retrieving the "name" and "id" attributes but you just gave me an idea. I'm going to try what you suggest about navigating via code.

Comment: @Ploppy I changed the parameters in setMode to `setMode(mode, category_id)` instead of the `$event` and now it's working as intended. Also changed navigation as you suggested and it worked. I don't remember why I chose to use `$event`. Could you write an answer so I can mark it as correct please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your `setMode()` method so that it sends the parameters instead of the event, it would be easier to manage.

```
setMode(mode, category_id)
```

If navigation seems to appear before your code executes, you should navigate using `this.router.navigate([...])` at the end of your `setMode()` method.